# What can Prettier do that Eslint cannot?

Tags: javascript, eslint, prettier

Eslint has so many rules by now that I don’t really see the reason to use Prettier as well. When I hit Save. Eslint fixes and formats my code already.
What can Prettier do that Eslint cannot?
Why do I need both.

Answer (score 1):

Main difference is that ESlint is specific to Javascript or its libraries and frameworks. In other hand prettier can be used for almost all Languages .